# What does / and _ mean in html?

Tags: html

What does _ and / mean in HTML?  I am trying to add an image to my site and would like to know what those functions do?

I've tried looking through google for the answer.

Comment: Those aren't functions.  Those are just characters like any other.  It's not really clear what you're trying to ask.

Comment: HTML does not have functions...

Comment: Can you show us the code where you’ve seen this?

Answer (score 0):

(I initially wrote this answer thinking you were asking about javascript instead of html; just in case I've included both here because, eh, why not.)

#### HTML

`_` has no specific meaning, it's just a letter.

`/` is used in file paths (such as URLs) to denote a change in directory. So `<img src="/foo/bar/baz.gif">` would find an image named "baz.gif" inside a directory named "bar" inside a directory named "foo", at the root level of the website.  For more detail, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

#### Javascript

As in HTML, `_` is just a character; it has no specific meaning in javascript.   It is used by a common utility library named "[underscore](https://underscorejs.org)", and a competing library named "[lodash](https://lodash.com)"; if you're seeing this in js code it's probably including one of those libraries.  (This is similar to how `$` is commonly used for jQuery.)

`/` does have a specific meaning in javascript; it's used to denote a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), or as the "division" symbol for math.

Comment: Thanks Daniel that makes perfect sense.